# SQL for joining two tables and grouping by shared column

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I want to join two tables and use the column they both share to group the results, including a null result for those accountIds which only appear in one table.

Table a

| AccountId | productApurchases |
| --- | --- |
| Steve | 1 |
| Jane | 5 |
| Bill | 10 |
| Abed | 2 |

Table b

| AccountId | productApurchases |
| --- | --- |
| Allan | 1 |
| Jane | 10 |
| Bill | 2 |
| Abed | 1 |
| Mike | 2 |

Desired output

| AccountId | productApurchases | productBpurchases |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Steve | 1 | 0 |
| Jane | 5 | 10 |
| Bill | 10 | 2 |
| Abed | 2 | 1 |
| Mike | 0 | 2 |

I've been trying with various joins but cannot figure out how to group by all the account ids.

Any advice much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use `full join`:

```
select accountid,
       coalesce(productApurchases, 0) as productApurchases,
       coalesce(productBpurchases, 0) as productBpurchases
from a full join
     b
     using (accountid);
```